# open() system call waiting

Tags: c, posix

Is there an easy way, to get `open()` to wait until it's true? For example, if I call

```
file = open("lock", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
```

And if another process hits it, I want it to wait until that file does not exist, so it can be created again.

Comment: "*hits it*" hits what, please?

Comment: Are you askin about [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)-ing a [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html) on Linux? If so, please RTFM and edit your question (at least to add a Linux tag)!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: No, OP is asking about creating a lockfile and what to do in the case where it already exists and you want to wait for it to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux you could use `inotify` on the containing directory to block until the next change to the directory, then try `open` with `O_CREAT|O_EXCL` again. But this is not portable, and file creation is not the proper way to do locking anyway. You should probably ask a new question about the specifics of the locking problem you're actually trying to solve and look for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the file open in a loop, and if the file open fails, sleep for awhile then loop around again. Either loop infinitely or for some max period of time(n*sleep).

Are you trying to use a file to synchronize processess? Look into mutexes/semaphores.